# Do I violate a copyright law if I reconstruct the sound effect scenario, but use only my own sounds in it?

Tags: copyright

By "my own sounds", I mean that I generated them or bought them.

Answer (score 1):

For sounds that you buy, you probably cannot make modified copies, since the license for a digital original usually does not permit making a derived work. As for sounds that you record yourself, only you can permit creation of a derived work. So, yes to your own sounds, no to purchased sounds in the usual case, as far as the source is concerned.

As for the "sound effect scenario", that depends on what you mean by one. Meaning 1 refers to "arrangement of 'sound effect' recordings", something analogous to a musical score. In that case, the "sound effect scenario" is copyrighted just like a musical score is. The degree of copying in music infringement need not be complete / verbatim, and infringement is often found based on similarity to a protected original. The second refers to a scheme for digital filtering, such as Wahwah. In that case it depends on what you mean by "reconstructing". If you encountered a filter effect that you like and know how to create an analogous filter, you aren't copying anyone's expression of anything, so there's nothing protected. Alternatively, you might have access to technical specifications for the filter and you can re-create a filter that way (to be concrete, you extract 12 coefficients that characterize the filter, and write an independent program). It is dimly possible that the courts would find that those coefficients are the "expression" of the abstract idea underlying a sound effect (thus protected). It is more likely that they will hold that the coefficients are elements of an algorithm, which is not protected by copyright.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. What I learned is that I have only two options: a) to contact the author of the effect; b) to contact a lawyer and provide specific information.